# When to update the CoreData persistent container values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I have UIViewController with some info that is been pre-added previously, and in this UIViewController only shows the info in UITextFields so the user can update them anytime.

After the user writes in new values, I save the values in Core Data, specifically in `viewWillDisappear`. That was working perfectly fine.

Until I added `imagePickerController` so the user can edit the photo in a later time. When the `imagePickerController` is invoked, it triggers the `viewWillDisappear` which saves the data to CoreData.

I need to save the info when the user dismiss this UIViewController and go back to the main UITableViewController.

I'm not using UIButton to save the data manually, it's just like the native iOS Notes app where it saves the data automatically when you dismiss the note editor view.

I have tried to save the data in unwind segue but that didn't work either.

I also need to save the new info in this particular UIViewController. So please, let me know if there's another method for the ViewController life cycle that I can save to CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it an issue if the data is saved when the image picker is presented? It seems completely legit since you save the data automatically.

If this is not the case then you do not want to do this automatically but you want to do it explicitly. This means you need a save button or you need to override the back button so you are notified when user goes back. Still this produces other issues such as what happens if user swipes back to dismiss the view controller.

If anything for automatic saving I would suggest you to save whenever user changes a text field (or dismisses one). This is bulletproof also for the situations when user kills the application while editing.

All you need to make sure is that a new entity is not created if one already exists. This should be pretty simple; save the entity on a property in the view controller and if it is null, create one "on save" otherwise modify the current one. By publicly exposing the property you will also have an edit functionality out of the box by setting the value to the view controller before you navigate to it (when selecting it from table view for instance).

Comment: I thought it would be better to save to CoreData one time instead of accessing the same context to save when the user is not done editing yet. But for broad scenarios, yeah it's better as may the user abort editing anytime for any reason.

Comment: Well, that is "automatic". You may set some kind of locking so it does not save too often but since this is user-interaction-triggered it will be slow enough.